# Tensorflow: Pick a list of non-overlapping slices from a tensor based on an info from another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I have a output of a conv layer, *conv*, of shape Batch_size x H x W x C.
I also have another tensort with the shape Batch_size x None x 2. The latter tensor supplies a list of points (Height and Width coordinates) for each example in a bach (the list is of different length for each example). And I want to extract the Channel dimension for each of those points.

I tried using tf.gather, and tf.batch_gather, but both doesn't seem to be the right thing to use here.

Basically what I want is for each batch *b* to loop through the points: for each point *i* having its h_i (height coord) and w_i (coord) and return *conv*[b, h_i, w_j, :]. And then stack these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def pick_points(images, coords):
    coords = tf.convert_to_tensor(coords)
    s = tf.shape(coords)
    batch_size, num_coords = s[0], s[1]
    # Make batch indices
    r = tf.range(batch_size, dtype=coords.dtype)
    idx_batch = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(r, 1), [1, num_coords])
    # Full index
    idx = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(idx_batch, 2), coords], axis=2)
    # Gather pixels
    pixels = tf.gather_nd(images, idx)
    # Output has shape [batch_size, num_coords, num_channels]
    return pixels

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # 2 x 2 x 3 x 3
    images = [
        [
            [[ 1,  2,  3], [ 4,  5,  6], [ 7,  8,  9]],
            [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]],
        ],
        [
            [[19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27]],
            [[28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36]],
        ],
    ]
    # 2 x 2 x 2
    coords = [
        [[0, 1], [1, 2]],
        [[1, 0], [1, 1]],
    ]
    pixels = pick_points(images, coords)
    print(sess.run(pixels))
    # [[[ 4  5  6]
    #   [16 17 18]]
    #
    #  [[28 29 30]
    #   [31 32 33]]]
```